# What happens on the OS when the user changes the date/time?

Tags: filesystems, operating-systems, date-time

I'm just curious about a question: let's say we have a folder containing some very important files (could be the System32 directory). We know that the filesystem stores some information about their creation and modification dates. Let's say that they were created the 1st of January 2014.

What happens to those files, but in general to the global state of the filesystem, when the user changes the date of the system to, for example, one year back: the 1st of January **2013**?

Does this change affects in a certain way those files? How the OS reacts when it accesses to a file with "strange" data information like:

- Created: 1st of January 2014
- Last modified: 1st of January 2013

And, again, what if the user changed the date of the system to one year **forward**?

Comment: Lots of things might not work right -- backups, updates, licensed programs, etc.  The OS itself would generally not care (though likely some would give you warnings).

Comment: @Ramhound - Likely the OP is interested in circumventing an expired license.

Comment: (Do note that most modern operating systems sync there clocks off of the internet by default, so you'd have to take extra steps to prevent this.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The precise details depend on your operating system (which you do not state although I assume you mean some version of Windows because you mention system32), but in general timestamps are saved as the number of seconds since the 'epoch' (which is 1st January 1970 at midnight UTC for POSIX-compliant systems, and Jan 1st 1601 for some versions of Windows). When the system reads the timestamp from a file, it converts this number of seconds into the current local time for display.

When you change the clock on your computer, it does not change these timestamp numbers, it just changes how they are converted into human-readable times and dates.

Most systems don't care if timestamps of files are in the future, so setting the clock back a year or two will generally not have any effect. This is sometimes necessary, because if the battery backup for the computer's internal clock should go flat, and there is no internet connection, then the computer won't know what the real time is, and the operating system has to be designed to boot successfully in this situation.

There are some notable exceptions: Antivirus tools can detect this as a symptom of a virus infection. Software anti-piracy tools can also detect this as an attempt to extend a free trial period. The 'make' program used in software development relies on timestamps to determine what to build. And so on.

See [the microsoft developer library documentation for more details about Windows-specific issues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724290(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I've intentionally left out the type of OS, just to have a "general" answer. The conversion from epoch-time to local-time is pretty straightforward but it doesn't answer my real question: "How the OS reacts when it accesses to a file with *strange* data information?"

Comment: I've added some more blurb. Generally the answer is the OS doesn't care, but various application software may, depending on what it does and how it works.

Answer (score -1):

Details about Date and Time of an machine will be saved in "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\w32time\TimeProviders\NtpClient". Hence open the registry through "run" command and type as "regedit.exe. File Allocation Table will be present in the registry this will keep all the details and the changes made details. This will give information to the GLU(Graphics Language Utility) in the C Library will convert into Machine Readable Language. By this way machine accepts the changes and start's processing.